# Detect circle overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to trigger a hover function when ANY part of a fake cursor hovers over a circle.

I have played around with the X and Y positions of the fake cursor, but that only works well for one direction. Is there a smarter way to go about this?

Here's a pen showing what I'm trying to do: trigger a hover function when any part of the pink circle (fake cursor) touches the green circle.

https://codepen.io/Jessels/pen/LYPxmqx

```
$('.cursor')
  .eq(0)
  .css({
        left: e.pageX - 20,
        top: e.pageY - 5
  });
```

Comment: Even with the pen it's not clear what you're trying to do here. What does 'fake cursor' mean? The pink circle I assume...? We need details on what you're expecting to happen, and when

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I've edited my question - hopefully it's a bit clearer now about what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't think that you can do this with just css, because hover is limited to the location of the actual cursor, rather than the circle that you are moving around based on the position of the cursor. You could check the position of the cursor against where you know the circles to be in the mousemove handler though.

Answer (score 4):

You can add this to your mousemove event.

Here we are finding the intersections and if the "cursor" is within the circle.

Here is where I found this code: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SalixAlba/54Fb2/)

Here is my [CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/jONBQRw)

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {

  $('.cursor').eq(0).css({
    left: e.pageX - 25,
    top: e.pageY - 20
  });

  // circles
  var c1 = $('.cursor');
  var c2 = $('.circle');

  // radius
  var d1 = c1.outerWidth(true) / 2;
  var d2 = c2.outerWidth(true) / 2;

  // center of first circle
  var x1 = c1.offset().left + c1.width() / 2;
  var y1 = c1.offset().top + c1.height() / 2;

  // center of second circle
  var x2 = c2.offset().left + c2.width() / 2;
  var y2 = c2.offset().top + c2.height() / 2;

  function calc() {
    var a = d2;
    var b = d1;
    var c = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
    var d = (b * b + c * c - a * a) / (2 * c);
    var h = Math.sqrt((b * b) - (d * d));
    if (d < 0 || $.isNumeric(h)) {
      c2.css('background', 'blue');
    } else {
      c2.css('background', 'green');
    }
  }
  calc();


});
```

```css
.cursor {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 999;
  background: hotpink;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor"></div>

<div class="circle">
  <div class="inter1 inter"></div>
  <div class="inter2 inter"></div>
  <div>
```